# Solve the quadratic equation $(2-y)^4=3(2-y)^2+1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

> Solve $$(2-y)^4=3(2-y)^2+1$$

The answer is supposed to be $y=4\pm \sqrt{6+\frac{13}2}$.
I have tried to work this problem out but I cannot get the answer that is in the book.

Comment: Could you show us what you did?

Comment: Hint: set $(2-y)^2=z$, then your equation becomes $z^2=3z+1$.

Comment: I let u=(2-y)^2 then I was left with u^2-3u-1=0 I used the quadratic equation to solve for u and got 3+/- sqrt13/2 since I still needed to solve y, I set (2-y)^2=sqrt(3+sqrt13/2) then simplified and got y=2+/- sqrt(3/2+sqrt13/2) instead of 4+/-sqrt6+13/2 I may be missing a step in my process of solving it but I just can't figure why I am not getting the answer the book has.

Comment: first you should get $u = 3/2+-sqrt(13)/2$. You got something else.

Comment: Your equation is a quartic, so it has 4 roots (counting multiplicities). It doesn't look like a square, so the answer you are given is probably wrong.

Answer (score 1):

None of the 'book answers' you have provided represents a solution, instead the value listed at the end of these steps work correctly. I have listed my steps below. If you spot an error, please let me know:

1. We have:
   $$(2-y)^4=3(2-y)^2+1$$
2. let 
   $$u=(2-y)^2$$
3. Substituting in original equation, you get:
   $$u^2-3u-1=0 $$

Using quadratic formula to solve the equation for u, 
$$u=\frac{3\pm \sqrt{9+4}}{2}$$

That is:
$$u=\frac{3\pm \sqrt{13}}{2}$$

So far we found $u$, but we want to solve for $y$.

4. Equation in step 1 can be written as:
   $$u=(2-y)^2=4-4y+y^2$$
5. Which simplifies to:

$$y^2-4y+(4-u)=0$$

6. Note that we have already found the values of $u$, and we are solving for $y$ so we can apply the quadratic formula again, with y as a variable and u as a constant this time to get:

$$y=\frac{4\pm \sqrt{16-4(4-u)}}{2}$$

7. The above can be reduced to:

$$y=2\pm \sqrt{u}$$

8. We know the value of $u$ from step 3 above, so let's plug it in the above equation to get:

$$y=2\pm \sqrt{\frac{3\pm \sqrt{13}}{2}}$$

9. this results in the following values for $y$:
   $$y=3.817354021 , 0.182645979$$

This is the curve for:
$$f(y)=(2-y)^4-3(2-y)^2-1$$
[image]